# SQL move customer string data into other columns

Tags: sql-server

I want to move:

- `Paul` into the `first_name` column
- `Bradford` into the `last_name` column
- `Flat`, `numbers` and `B` into the `street_number` column
- `Great South Road` into the  `street_name` column
- `Manly` into the `region` column
- `Brisbane` into the `city` column
- `6010` into the `zip_code` column.

I want to be able to do the same for `Mike Bradford` but in a different row.
while keeping the string data in the `customer_address` column

*Note: All customer data given here is fake but I'm trying to find a solution for the real thing.*

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs6YR.png)

```
INSERT INTO online
       (
        customer_address
       )
 VALUES
      ('Paul Bradford Flat 9 6511B Great South Road Manly Brisbane 6010'),
      ('Mike Bradford Flat 321 11 Ongly Ave Manly Brisbane 6010')
     go
```

Comment: First, why are you SHOUTING? Seconds, how can you insert 2 values into 1 column?

Comment: I'm not shouting lol, second thing is data that comes in will be going into the customer_address column. I want to be able to move data for both customers why'll keeping it in the same row

Comment: With fake data this might work... Split at blanks and count the elements. But what about `Paul M. Bradford`? What about `Mickey Mouse Road`? With real data you will - very probably! - need manually corrections. A good example why **you should never ever store more than one information in one column! (1.NF)**

Comment: I agree but it has to be done this way. Could you point my in the right direction

Comment: This task is essentially impossible to get right in every case without an incredibly complex set of lookups on every possible address (plus several variations thereof) that you may get entered into your database.

Comment: This is impossible. Unless, your real data values are not delimited with some special character (`tab`, CHAR(31) or something else) which can be used to split the values.

Comment: They are spaced

Comment: I agree with everyone here, pretty much impossible to get 100% right. Where is the data coming from, is it in a file? If so, may be better to sort the file.

Comment: Is this question solved (as far as possible)? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(customer_address NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockup
       (
        customer_address
       )
 VALUES
      ('Paul Bradford Flat 9 6511B Great South Road Manly Brisbane 6010'),
      ('Mike Bradford Flat 321 11 Ongly Ave Manly Brisbane 6010');


WITH Splitted AS 
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT m.customer_address AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML) AS TheXML
    FROM @mockup AS m
)
SELECT TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS FirstName
      ,TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[2]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS LastName
      ,TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[3]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
                   + ' ' + TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[4]',N'nvarchar(max)')
                   + ' ' + TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[5]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS FlatNr
      ,TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[6]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
                   + ' ' + TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[7]',N'nvarchar(max)')
                   + ' ' + TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[8]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Road
      ,TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[9]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS city
      ,TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[10]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS zip_code
FROM Splitted
```

The result

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| FirstName | LastName | FlatNr       | Road             | city     | zip_code |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| Paul      | Bradford | Flat 9 6511B | Great South Road | Manly    | Brisbane |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| Mike      | Bradford | Flat 321 11  | Ongly Ave Manly  | Brisbane | 6010     |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

But you can see, that "Great South Road" (3 parts) and "Ongly Ave" (2 parts) mix this up. You might try something more sophisticated with counting zip and city from the back, but - with real data - there will be no fully working solution... This is impossible...

### UPDATE Update your table

Try it with an *updateable CTE*

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(customer_address NVARCHAR(MAX),FirstName VARCHAR(100),LastName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup
       (
        customer_address
       )
 VALUES
      ('Paul Bradford Flat 9 6511B Great South Road Manly Brisbane 6010'),
      ('Mike Bradford Flat 321 11 Ongly Ave Manly Brisbane 6010');


WITH Splitted AS 
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT m.customer_address AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML) AS TheXML
    FROM @mockup AS m
)
UPDATE Splitted
       SET FirstName = TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
          ,LastName =  TheXML.value(N'(/x/text())[2]',N'nvarchar(max)')

SELECT * FROM @mockup
```

Comment: Almost but I need to move the data not put it into a new table

Answer (score 0):

You can use persisted columns,
for example:

```
alter table online add [first_name] as (left(customer_address,4))
```

but it will work only with fake data, because user's data may be something like this: 'Mike B. Boy 321 Flat Age 11 loves bananas and pizza'

Answer (score 0):

You required to provide columns individually:

```
INSERT INTO online
       (
            first_name, last_name, street_number, street_name, region, city, zipcode
       )
 VALUES
      ('Paul', 'Bradford', 'Flat 9 6511B', 'Great South Road', 'Manly', 'Brisbane', '6010'),
      ('Mike', 'Bradford', 'Flat 321 11' ,'Ongly Ave', 'Manly' ,'Brisbane', '6010')
     go
```

Comment: This is no answer to the question. The question is how to do this automatically out of concatenated data...

Comment: If I could I would but I can't. I like this as its simple but I'm not able to do this.

Comment: Lets see... Lets check with question poster... He might be asking this as the first step...